# Inject new expressions after AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have an AJAX request in my Angular app and it gets details from the server. I want to inject these details into an already loaded partial. There are no loops or anything, just loading this information. For example if I have `$scope.properties_address = data.properties_address;` in the success function of my AJAX call, how do I inject it as an expression like `{{properties_address}}` into my partial?

Comment: What do you mean by "already loaded partial"? I'm not aware of the term "partial" being used in an Angular context. I've heard it in the context of ASP.NET MVC, but that tag is not present. Also, you'd just put that expression in the HTML of your partial, then bind to it.

Comment: Angular builds one-page apps. When it loads the index.html, the other pages that are loaded on the page via `ng-view` are known as partials - hence I tagged it Angular.

Comment: I've usually heard those referred to as views or templates. I'm also not clear on why you wouldn't just include the expression in your partial. If you are going back and adding expressions after the fact, it sounds like you have a design problem. Maybe load a different view with those expressions? Otherwise, you'll need to get into `$compile` and all that fun.

Comment: What is jQuery's role in this? If you're using jQuery for AJAX, for example, you're going to have to `$scope.apply()`. If you instead use Angular's `$http` service, you won't have to force a digest cycle. Also, what is the markup of your partial? Please post all of your code so we can help you debug. If you can, create a demo at https://plnkr.co or https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `$scope.apply()` is the correct answer @couzzi. The new expressions were applied to the page instantly! If you like you can add this answer to help others and I will flag it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$scope.$apply()` in the `success` or `done` blocks of your Ajax call. This which will bindings and watchers.

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in AngularJS from outside of the AngularJS framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the AngularJS framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply